# Do highlight text from nested html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do highlight text by jquery , but I can't figure it out anymore . Actually I got html element from API when I search in input box .But It is return included with html tag in response so I don't want to hightlight `html tag` .I want highlight only the text from that api response . Please look at below , I want to highlight only `@dd` from `a tag` only .

```js
var fromAPI = '<p><span data-email="dd@gmail.com" data-id="24" data-label="@dd" class="mention"><a>@dd</a></span> </p>';
var search = "@dd";
var final = hl(fromAPI);
function hl(p) {
  if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(p)) {
    p = $(p).attr('id','ddd');
    p = $(p).html($(p)[0].outerHTML);
    hl(p);
  } else {
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+search+")","gi");
    p = $(p).html().replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    $(p).html($(p)[0].outerHTML);
  }
  return p;
}
console.log($(final).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

actual Result :

`<p id="ddd"><span data-email="dd@gmail.com" data-id="24" data-label="@dd" class="mention"><a>@dd</a></span> </p>`

Expected Result:

`<p id="ddd"><span data-email="dd@gmail.com" data-id="24" data-label="@dd" class="mention"><a><mark>@dd</mark></a></span> </p>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working on most parts, you just made one mistake by calling the function `h1` recursively. Problem is the following code:

```
var final = hl(fromAPI);
hl(p);
```

You are setting `final` as the return of the function `h1` but that function calls itself again, losing the callback to the variable.

I copied your code to a JSFiddle and changed it so u can try it yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/qg6ffpLg/

I just replaced `h1(p);` with the exact code in your else statement (just an example to show you that your code works except for the part where u call the function twice.

Comment: Hey If my search word is `dd` , this can also change my html attribute ! I don't want that ..

Comment: That's part of your own regex, anyways.. to fix it you could add [^"] to your regex. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qg6ffpLg/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am solving by giving temp id in each child element like below . Currently this solve my problem.If there any better solution, please share me !!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fromAPI = '<p><span data-email="dd@gmail.com" data-id="24" data-label="@dd" class="mention"><a>@dd</a></span> </p>';
    var search = "@dd";
    var last = highlight.init(fromAPI,search);
    console.log(last);
});
    //highlight text object
    var highlight = {
      _id : 'highlight_search_result_history-',
      childNode : 0,
      search : '',
      init : function(d,sKey) {
         $("<div id='"+this._id+"'>").html(d).appendTo("body");
         highlight.search = sKey;
         this.result('#'+this._id);
         return this.finalize();
      },
      result : function(p) {
          var id = this._id + (this.childNode++);
          var p = $(p).children();
          $(p).attr('id',id);
          if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test($(p).html())) {
            this.result('#'+id);
          } else {
            var pattern = new RegExp("("+highlight.search+")","gi");
            var highlightText = $(p).text().replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
            $(p).html(highlightText);
          }
      },
      finalize : function() {
         //remove temp id
         for(var j = 0;j <= this.childNode;j++) {
             $("#"+this._id+j).removeAttr("id");
         }
         var highlightText = $("#"+this._id).html();
         //delete temp id
         $("#"+this._id).remove();
         return highlightText;
      }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already gave you the right solution / answer... did you even try it or check the JSFiddle (updated) I provided. Those iD's and pointless for loops in your code make no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I don't really know how many nested html element will come out from API. It is not working if I put one more element is added to your jsFiddle .

Comment: Then your doing something else wrong, which has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: Yeah , I forget to mention that